# AngularJS HelloWorld nothing show when run app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am started learning angularJs and on first setup, app wont work.
What is wrong in my code? I'am try everything and I don't have any idea what to do.
When run in browser it show only html, but message not showing? Please help!

Here is index.html

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en-US" ng-app="helloWorldApp">

    <head>
        <title>Angular Hello, Mordor</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="AngularJS Tutorial App">
        <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    </head>


    <body>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
```

here is code in main.html and show.html where showing message

```
<div>{{message}}</div>
```

then app.js

```
// Chapter2/app.js

'use strict';
// App Module

var helloWorldApp = angular.module('helloWorldApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'helloWorldControllers'
]);

helloWorldApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    }).when('/show', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/show.html',
        controller: 'ShowCtrl'
});

$locationProvider.html5mode(false).hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

And Controllers.js

```
//  chap2/controllers.js

'use strict';
// Controllers

var helloWorldControllers = angular.module('helloWorldControllers', []);

helloWorldControllers.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http',
    function MainCtrl($scope, $location, $http) {
        $scope.message = "hello Mordor.";
    }]);

helloWorldControllers.controller('ShowCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http',
    function ShowCtrl($scope, $location, $http) {
        $scope.message = "Show the World";
    }]);
```

Comment: Where exactly are your route templates? Your code says `partials/main.html` / `partials/show.html` but the HTML comments show `chapter2/main.html` / `chapter2/show.html`

Comment: Route tamplate is in partials/main.html and partials/show.html

Comment: I see this error in the console ~ *"TypeError: $locationProvider.html5mode is not a function"*. You probably meant `html5Mode` (capital "M"). Fixed here ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/siXKQtxFOgB1HQAw0X1j?p=preview

Comment: Voting to close as a typo. FYI, the very **first** thing you should do when you encounter a problem is check your console for errors

Comment: Also, when you run into problems in Angular always switch to the non-min versions of the Angular libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I whipped up a simplified example based on yours that works. I am not sure why yours doesn't show any error, but the main issue was that you had a typo in `html5Mode`. Here is a working example Plunker based on your code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/MZIxG2sasm1hV1vA21Fa?p=preview

Notice that you had a case error in your html5Mode function, you had mode in lower case:

```
helloWorldApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        }).when('/show', {
            templateUrl: 'show.html',
            controller: 'ShowCtrl'
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');
    }
]);
```

Comment: Other than the paths to the template files (which we can only assume are correct in OP's code), how is this any different?

Comment: Yes in Plunker work, I am copy/paste your code from plunker and again get big nothing.

Comment: @strava1 if you copy / paste this code, won't the paths to your templates be incorrect?

Comment: Answers to typographical / syntax related problems don't tend to help anybody in future. It's better to point out the issue in comments and vote to close the question

Answer (score 0):

First and fore most mitake you are missing the ng-app which is the bootstrapper for angular

```
<html ng-app="helloWorldApp">
<head>
    <title>Angular Hello, Mordor</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="AngularJS Tutorial App">
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: means? Can you eloborate? why is that it should not be in html tag?

Comment: Sorry, I checked the documentation. I deleted my comment. The docs say that it can be on the <html> tag. I also verified in my own code that putting ng-app on the <html> does work. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem. @Toddsden. :)

Comment: See my answer for an example of using ng-app on the <html> tag.